# jQuery hide() doesn't work well

Tags: jquery, html, css

Dear all,

I've faced the following problem for a while. Please help me out!

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />


  <!--css stylesheet-->
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!--jQuery external javascript - CDN-->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="header"></div>

  <div class="content"><input type="button" id="sendData" value="send your data" align="center"></div>

  <div class="barChart"><input type="button" id="reenterButton" value="Re-enter">     </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 650px;
  height: 650px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}



.barChart {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 650px;
  height: 650px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  display: none;            // Make .barchart hide initially
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#sendData").button()                   
                .click(function() {        
                  $("div.content").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, "slow", function() {
                    $("div.barChart").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, "slow");
                  });
                 }); 

  $("#reenterButton").button()
                 .click(function() {
                  $("div.barchart").hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, "slow", function() {   
                    $("div.content").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, "slow");
                  });
                 });
});
</script>
```

The *#sendData* button **works** fine, but the click on *#reenterButton* **doesn't** work on the second statement(The one with the selector(*"div.barchart"*)).

*.barchart* doesn't hide after applying the click action on reenter button.

Is the situation related to the div status I set in css file? Or something else?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle and link it.

Comment: tried hiding first and then showing ?

Comment: @Deepanshu: Thanks for mentioning it. But it still doesn't work. .barchart still not hiding.

Comment: it working check here http://jsfiddle.net/DbbYp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on the second click binding, instead of  `$("div.barchart")` it should be `$("div.barChart")`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXyV7/)